# Необходимо выгрузить из таблицы все повторяющиеся номера телефонов

Tags: mysql, sql

в столбце number содержатся несколько тысяч номеров, нужно выгрузить те, которых в ней содержится больше всего.

Answer (score 1):

**Для mysql**

Если нужно 10 самых частых

```
SELECT `number`, count(*) cnt 
   FROM `yourtable` 
   group by `number` 
   order by cnt 
   desc limit 10
```

или так если нужно те, что встречаются больше 100 раз

```
SELECT `number`, count(*) cnt 
   FROM `yourtable` 
   group by `number` 
   having cnt > 100 
   order by cnt
```

Comment: спасибо! к сожалению выходит общее число(

Comment: нужно, чтобы выгрузились все номера телефонов, которые встречаются в списке более 1-2 раз.

Comment: к сожалению выходит общее число - это как? вы водит номер и сколько раз встретился. Чтобы получить только номера без счетчика еще один селект сверху напишите `select number from (...) t`

Comment: @Stas *нужно, чтобы выгрузились все номера телефонов, которые встречаются в списке более 1-2 раз* Затребовать "1 раз" и надеяться НЕ получить какие-то номера - это верх оптимизма...

Comment: выходят 2 столбца number и cnt и в number указано значение number, a в cnt  число 65442554(((

Comment: Это как - что, у всех?